# Mysql #1146 table doesn't exist - fault with Wordpress or mysql?

Tags: mysql, linux, wordpress

I have a wordpress page which just shows a white page in the browser when I try to go to it. I checked plugins and themes if there was something wrong with them. But the error seems to be the databases:

In phpmyadmin when I click any database and then on any table in the database, I get the error "#1146 the table (table name) doesn't exist".

The only recent thing I've done (unless I did something else by mistake) is to export one database to a folder on my computer.

Any ideas how I can fix the databases?

Edit:
I have multiple websites on my wordpress installation. But it's just one of them that doesn't work. So I'm confused as to what might be wrong.

Comment: How did you export that database? just copied (or moved!!) those files?
have you tried moving those files back to where they came from?

Comment: I clicked the database in phpmyadmin, then clicked on the export-tab. And from there exported it to my computer. I entered mysql now in the terminal and checked if the databases and their content was still there, and it's still there. So seems to something wth phpmyadmin?

Comment: show me query and database table

Comment: Are there any underscores or spaces in the database name?

Comment: This type of error usually indicates a problem with the underlying files in the MySQL data directory. Check the MySQL error log, check permissions of the files in the datadir, and maybe try connecting from the MySQL command line client to see if you're able to see the databases and tables from there.